# Returning Boolean value from Asynctask in Android

Tags: java, android, android-asynctask, status

I am new to android. What i want to do is just pass a URL to Asynctask and then check if return status code SC_OK or not. The method should return true if the status code SC_OK is returned and false if any other status code.

```
class checking extends AsyncTask<String, Void, Boolean> {

    @Override
    protected Boolean doInBackground(String... params) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        Boolean a;
        HttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient();
        HttpGet httpGet = new HttpGet(l1);      
        HttpResponse response;
        try {
            response = client.execute(httpGet);
            StatusLine statusLine = response.getStatusLine();
            int statusCode = statusLine.getStatusCode();
            if (statusCode != HttpStatus.SC_OK) {                                   
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"No", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                a= false;
            }
            else {
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Yes", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                a= true; 
            }
        } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        finally{
            return false;
        }              
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Boolean result) {

    }
}
```

Comment: And what's the problem?

Comment: a `finally` block is always called so you will always return false. Maybe you want to remove this block and add return a; at the end?

Comment: Was not working but works fine now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change the whole thing to (blind coding):

```
class checking extends AsyncTask<String, Void, Boolean> {
    @Override
    protected Boolean doInBackground(String... params) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        Boolean a;
        HttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient();
        HttpGet httpGet = new HttpGet(l1);
        HttpResponse response;
        try {
            response = client.execute(httpGet);
            StatusLine statusLine = response.getStatusLine();
            int statusCode = statusLine.getStatusCode();
            if (statusCode != HttpStatus.SC_OK) {
                a = false;
            } else {
                a = true;
            }
            return a;
        } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return false;
    }
    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Boolean result) {
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), (result ? "Yes" : "No"), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You're setting your local Boolean `a` to `true` but then never returning that value. The method, as it's written, will always return `false`.